# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm running into this issue and I can't find anything on it, I believe it has something to do with my connection string? A few classmates ran into this problem but the connection string their using doesn't work for me. Can't figure this one out. Thoughts?

SERVER.JS:

```js
var express = require("express");
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fuckface')


var QuoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:  { type: String, required: true, minlength: 10},
    quote: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 30 },
}, {timestamps: true });

mongoose.model('Quote', QuoteSchema);
var Quote = mongoose.model('Quote');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"))
app.use(session({
    secret: 'kingmonkey',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))

app.get('/showform', function(request, response) {

    response.render('showform')
})

app.get('/showquotes', function(request, response) {
    Quote.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('You need a different career')
        } else {
        response.render('showquotes', {quotes: data})
        }
    })
})

app.post('/processquote', function(request, response) {
    var quoteInstance = new Quote()
    console.log(request.body, '<<< QUOTE INSTANCE')
    quoteInstance.name = request.body.name
    quoteInstance.quote = request.body.quote
    console.log(quoteInstance.name, quoteInstance.quote)
    quoteInstance.save(function(err){
        console.log('Oopsie dasies, it didnt save')
    })
    response.redirect('showquotes')
})


app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log('king me 8000')
})
```

SHOWFORM.EJS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="quotes" action="/processquote" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
            Quote: <textarea placeholder="Enter your quote" name="quote" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EXPRESS TRACE:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:30200) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
king me 8000
(node:30200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017]
{ name: 'er;ofijer;oigj',
  quote: 'erlkfurnfoerfenrfih3riufhi',
  submit: 'submit' } '<<< QUOTE INSTANCE'
er;ofijer;oigj erlkfurnfoerfenrfih3riufhi
```

MongoDB TRACE:

```
2018-07-09T16:32:40.473-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2018-07-09T16:32:40.546-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-07-09T16:32:40.552-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mongodb connection url dose not have port. Try this one

```
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {    
   console.log(`mongoose connection open to ${dbUrl}`); 
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {    
  console.log(`mongoose connection err: `, err); 
});
```